# Spring JPA : setting the charactere set in native query

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having a query like:

```sql
 @Query(value = "select foo from bar where arg='supplémentaire'", nativeQuery = true)
 GreenEntity findFoo();
```

The database is Postgres and running :

`SHOW SERVER_ENCODING`

return UTF8.

The queried table contains indeed a field `arg` having for value `supplémentaire`

However, doing a select on this table won't send `supplémentaire` as expected but `supplÃ©mentaire` query to return nothing.

Added the following properties to the Spring properties file but this won't fix the issue, nor will `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://xx:5432/yy?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`:

```
spring.sql.init.encoding= UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.charset = UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.enabled = true
server.servlet.encoding.force = true
#spring.mandatory-file-encoding = UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding = UTF-8
spring.messages.encoding = UTF-8
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

Any ideas how this issue can be fixed ?

NOTE: Using springboot 2.6.6 and associated spring dependencies.

Comment: On MySQL it is working even without all these additional properties for setting UTF-8. Did you try without them? As you may accidently put space after one of these properties, and "UTF-8" became "UTF-8 " and java did not recognize it and fall back to default.

Comment: Just an idea: The problem might be that characters with diacritics often have multiple encodings: as a single symbol, or as character + diacritic.  Not sure if Postgres handles this correctly (whatever you consider the correct handling). See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E9 under "Decomposition"

Comment: "However, doing a select on this table won't send supplémentaire as expected but supplÃ©mentaire query to return nothing." Who is sending what? are you talking about the SQL query, or the result? Where exactly are you seeing this?